# What does such a construction mean in C?

Tags: c

```
*(&v69 + v15) = (double)(char)(*((_BYTE *)v14 + v15) ^ 0x80) * 0.0078125;
```

What does *(&v69 + v15) on the left side of the expression mean in this construction?

v69 is the variable declared above.

```
float v69;
```

Comment: `*(&x + y)` is the same as `x[y]` I believe

Comment: @MortenJensen: Acutally that's `*(x + y)`. So this is `(&x)[y]`

Comment: @Joshua `float v69;` <-- v69 is not a pointer, but if it was yes - it would be equivalent to `*(x + y)`. If you do `*(x + y)` where x is a float, you should be getting errors about making pointers from int/float without casts

Comment: Unless `v15` is always 0, `*(&v69 + v15)` exhibits _undefined behavior_. Also, the `(char)` cast will give different numbers depending on whether the `char` type is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @IanAbbott: I actually came up with an alternate hypothesis. We now know it's not true in OP's case, but under certain constraints this can be made valid. Certain compilers guarantee things like memory layout of global variables in a way that makes this construct work. It's still terrible to depend on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (confirmed by OP) reverse-compiled code.

Take the address of variable v69 and add v15 to it and dereference the result as a pointer and assign to it. It makes sense.

But there's a problem waiting for you. If not passed back through the exact same compiler again, variable rearrangement will break the corresponding algorithm. The code needs to be rewritten making the array of floats in the appropriate place. That is, the declaration of `v69` should look like `float v69[some-number]`.

Comment: @Eluvium: In the future please make that clear in your question.  It's very important context.